# Serializing multiple huge maps in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, serialization, hashmap

I want to serialize multiple maps where key type is BitSet and value is a List. Currently there are 8 maps with ~430k elements each. Each key is a bitset that contains 4096 bits.

My problem lies in the size of produced file, not in the procedure itself.
Whenever I do this the standard way:

```
    SerializationUtils.ensurePathExists(filePath);
    DeflaterOutputStream fstream = new DeflaterOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath.toFile()));
    ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(fstream);
    ostream.writeObject(object);
    ostream.close();
```

or using Kryo and its UnsafeOutput - I always end up with a file of size ~220mb.

Meanwhile serializing exact same data structure in python (using the pickle module) results in file of size ~100mb.

From what I've seen BitSet class even declares optimal serialization routine (writing the minimal amount of info). My only guess is that the extra ~100mb comes from some kind of JVM meta overhead - but isn't it a bit too much? Is there any way to cut that extra 100mb?

Comment: @Eugene That's not correct. Metadata is produced, for example the `serialVersionUId` value we have been discussing, and class names, and field names and type tags. See the Protocol section of the Object Serialization Speification.

Comment: @Eugene Clearly it is a lot *more* than what Python does. You seem to be just guessing about both.

Comment: @Eugene Well please don't. You're just causing confusion. Please delete all this. You've posted barely one correct word here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for what Python does, but Java goes to a lot of trouble to ensure that you can vary the class definition in various ways without breaking compatibility with serialized streams. For example, fields are serialized along with their names and types, not relying on the order in the class definition. All this adds serialization protocol overhead. You are correct that `BitSet` is serialized minimally, and the same goes for all the JRE `List` implementations However that may not apply to whatever class you have in your `List`.

By contrast one can imagine a serialization protocol that just copies the bytes directly from the instance object, and requires that the class not change at all between serialization and deserialization; or that serializes types but not names, for example, all of which would save space compared with what Java does to meet its design goals.